# Populating Angular Reactive Forms correcctly

Tags: javascript, angular

In an angular 7 app, I have created a list of managers. When a user clicks on an item, a view with a populated form should be displayed where the user can then update the manager details. While my view is shown, the manager details doesn't show in the form itself and I can see two errors in the console

> ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of null
>       at ManagerViewComponent.push../src/app/manager/manager-view/manager-view.component.ts.ManagerViewComponent.initForm

This is what my code looks like at the moment.

.ts

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { ManagerService } from "./../../services/manager.service";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-manager-view",
  templateUrl: "./manager-view.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./manager-view.component.css"]
})
export class ManagerViewComponent implements OnInit {
  editManagerForm: FormGroup;
  manager = null;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private managerService: ManagerService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.managerDetails();
    this.initForm();
  }

  private initForm() {
    let firstname = this.manager.firstname;
    let lastname = this.manager.lastname;
    let username = this.manager.username;
    let password = this.manager.password;
    let terminal = this.manager.terminal.name;

    this.editManagerForm = new FormGroup({
      firstname: new FormControl(firstname),
      lastname: new FormControl(lastname),
      username: new FormControl(username),
      password: new FormControl(password),
      terminal: new FormControl(terminal)
    });
  }

  managerDetails() {
    const managerId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");

    this.managerService.getManager(managerId).then(data => {
      this.manager = data;
    });
  }
```

.html

```
<form id="editManager" [formGroup]="editManagerForm">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-6 form-group">
        <label for="">Firstname</label>
        <input
        formControlName="firstname"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        />
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 form-group">
        <label for="">Lastname</label>
        <input
        formControlName="lastname"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-6 form-group">
        <label for="terminal">Bus Terminal</label>
        <select formControlName="terminal" class="form-control">
        <option selected>{{ manager.terminal.name }}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let terminal of terminals" [ngValue]="terminal">
            {{ terminal.name }}
        </option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- <p>{{ editManagerForm.value | json }}</p> -->
</form>
```

In app.module.ts I have both `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` imported correcctly like this

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
```

Apparently I am doing something wrong since this is my first attempt at populating reactive forms. Please help me fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to make the following changes when you initialise your editManagerForm. You should use a [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#generating-form-controls-with-formbuilder) to generate your Form Group and Form Controls.

Do remember to import formBuilder and formGroup on your component.

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
.
.
constructor(
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
) { }

editManagerForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    firstName: [null],
    lastName: [null],
    username: [null],
    password: [null],
    terminal: [null],
}
```

I assume you will populate the `editManagerForm` on the `managerDetails()` method. You can achieve this by using [patchValue](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value):

```
managerDetails() {
  const managerId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");

  this.managerService.getManager(managerId).then(data => {
    this.editManagerForm.patchValue(data);
  });
}
```

---

Note: I am assuming that the data you fetched from `getManager()` is an object in the following format

```
data = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  terminal: ''
}
```

Comment: `patchValue` wow, haven't seen it used in the tutorials I have been watching since. Using it in the managerDetails method as advised solve the issue.